# Access update query based on 2 field values in another table

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to run an update query based on 2 fields in a seperate table. I know how to do it based on one field, add the two tables, create a join between the two related fields and run the update. However when I try and run it with two joins it says it cannot execute because it contains ambiquous joins. Here's a brief example of what I'm trying to achieve

Table 1 contains name, location and number of items.
Table 2 contains name, location and and empty field for the number of items.

When i try update table 2 with the information from table 1, with a join between the 2 name fields, it updates the same number of items for each different location.

UPDATE:

I've fixed it, I think I was linking the joins incorrectly.

Here's the finished SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Tbl_Hourly_Pick_Performance 
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Temp_Count_Info 
  ON (Tbl_Hourly_Pick_Performance.[Sign On]=Tbl_Temp_Count_Info.[Picker ID]) 
  AND (Tbl_Hourly_Pick_Performance.[Pick Floor]=Tbl_Temp_Count_Info.Floor) 
SET Tbl_Hourly_Pick_Performance.[No of Stores] = Tbl_Temp_Count_Info.Count;
```

Comment: please paste the wrong query

Comment: Please post the sql. Mostly ambiguous joins mean that you should include a subquery.